# SQLite Syntax Error Near (Result)

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm getting this error thrown when I try to query for a value in a SQLite DB:

```
SQLite error (1): near "Incident": syntax error
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' in System.Data.SQLite.dll
```

The SQLite DB has one table with one record in it currently.

Table ' AssociationList ' has columns RecID, BusinessObjectID, and Association.

There's one row in the table that has the following values (In order of columns above):

```
1, 6dd53665c0c24cab86870a21cf6434ae, Incident
```

I have a .NET application that is referencing System.Data.SQLite, and runs the following to execute a scalar query to find the Association column value (here it's 'Incident') for the matching BusinessObjectID (That 42 digit string above).

```
ExecuteScalar(TrebuchetDB.ExecuteScalar("Select Association From AssociationList Where BusinessObjectID = '" & BusObID & "' ;"))
```

My ExecuteScalar function is below:

```
Public Function ExecuteScalar(ByVal sql As String) As String
    Dim cnn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection(dbConnection)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim mycommand As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(cnn)
    mycommand.CommandText = sql
    Dim value As Object = mycommand.ExecuteScalar()
    cnn.Close()
    If value IsNot Nothing Then
        Return value.ToString()
    End If

    Return ""
End Function
```

**My question specifically is what could be causing this syntax error on the Result of my query** (That 'Incident' value appearing in the error message at the top)?

Coincidentally, I am able to get this scalar query working on the same sub 'ExecuteScalar()' by querying the RecID value below, which returns a value without an error... It's just this one where I try to compare the BusinessObjectID value (Which is a Varchar in the SQLite DB)

```
ExecuteScalar("Select Association From AssociationList Where RecID = 1")
```

Comment: tldr: 1) use placeholders and 2) look at the *actual* value of `sql` when the exception is generated (use the debugger) - why *is* this invalid?

Comment: Apparently `BusObID` has a value not of that GUID/hex looking thing, but Association. Use the debugger to view said value.  That method though has some issues: you should wrap the connection and command objects in Using blocks so they are disposed and your app doesnt leak.  And always use SQL parameters, never concat queries like that.  Combined, that method becomes more trouble than it is worth

Comment: @Plutonix I'm checking the BusObID value before it's being sent to this query, it's definitely the value 6dd53665c0c24cab86870a21cf6434ae. Incident isn't being sent in the select query, it's the result. "Incident" is the value I'm trying to get, I don't know it at the time I'm sending the query, which is the purpose of that table (The data I have at the time I send the query is the 42 digit BusObID, I'm trying to match it to that Association column for a lookup)

Comment: What line does it throw the exception on?  (VS appears to be disagreeing with your assessment)

Comment: It throws on *Dim value As Object = mycommand.ExecuteScalar()* in the ExecuteScalar() function

Comment: Note: The raw sql `...Where RecID = 1` is **not the same** as the way that "helper" gets the SQL.  For it, the param is ticked: `Where BusinessObjectID = '42'` that is, as string rather than integer.  SQLite is typeless which means you can store any type in any column.  Thats why Parmeters are especially important with SQLite

Comment: Because you are trying to execute the scalar in the params of your function... `ExecuteScalar(TrebuchetDB.ExecuteScalar("Select Association From AssociationList Where BusinessObjectID = '" & BusObID & "' ;"))`, you need to pass just your query... what is happening is inside the params it is executing and returning the string you want, but then you are passing that string to call the DB again... and hence your problem...

Comment: Set a breakpoiint in that "helper" and step thru it....better yet, get rid of it.  (`Dim anything As Object` is almost always a mistake as well).  @Codexer Nice.  I didnt notice the nested call.

Comment: @Plutonix a lot of the jargon you're using is going right over my head... What does "The param is ticked" even mean? How is that scenario different with parameters as opposed to including a value directly in the query? I never use parameters in SQL... What might that command look like otherwise?

Comment: Yup! Hes returning the value he needs that is nested but that is then assigned as his query and then called again... thanks @Plutonix!

Comment: You'll have to do some research, but I spelled it out with an example `1` vs `'42'`.  Ticks are **not** all purpose SQL delimiters.  By putting ticks around a numeric Id you are casting it to string

Comment: You're both completely right. I'm an idiot. The nested call was unintentional and was the entire issue. @Plutonix was right from the beginning in calling out that I was sending the value "incident" when I didn't believe I was so. It was doing that because of the nested call. I think I messed up some sort of auto-complete when typing it out. Thanks for the patience guys.

Comment: There are many more things to fix there - such helpers are almost always more trouble than they a worth.

Comment: * rather I think I copied and pasted more than I thought I did from a different section of code.... my bad

Comment: Yup, glad you are good to go, happy coding friend!

Comment: @Plutonix I'm at such a novice level right now, this is a starting point and I'll have to learn a lot before I get to the point where I fix the other issues. I rarely have to do anything in SQL other than some basic select queries, and those are usually queries I get to execute happily from SSMS and not have to worry about doing so from .NET.... I'll definitely look into fixing this up a bit later but for now I was just trying to edge in a proof-of-concept for a hobby app while I had a few hours tonight. Thanks a ton!

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd link](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png)

Comment: That ⬆ never gets old hajaj!